# I know this is wrong, but why?

Tags: calculus

The geometric series is

$$\frac{1}{1 -x} = \sum_{n \geq 1} |x|^n$$

Why is it not correct to do the following?

$$f(\frac{1}{1 -x} )= \sum_{n \geq 1} f(|x|^n)$$

I tried this out with $\log(1-x)$ and the series on wikia is nothing alike. Any tricks to get the taylor series for natural log quickly without doing all the messy calculations?

Comment: There is no Taylor series for $\log(x)$ about $0$, since $\log(0)$ is not defined. You can find the series about $1$, easily from the geometric series.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq \mathbf{0}}x^n\ne\sum_{n\geq\mathbf{1}}|x|^n =\frac{|x|}{1-|x|}$$where $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because

$$f(\frac 1 {1 - x}) = f(\sum\limits_{n \ge 0} x^n)$$

whenever $|x| < 1$. In general, $f(a + b) \ne f(a) + f(b)$.

Do note that you've got a mistake in writing the original geometric series.

---

Regarding getting the Taylor series for the logarithm function, which I will assume you want to compute near $x = 1$, use the fact that ($f(x) = \ln{x}$)

$$f'(x) = \frac 1 x, f''(x) = \frac {-1} {x^2}, f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{2}{x^3}, f^{(4)}(x) = \frac{-3 \cdot 2}{x^4}$$

and so on. Do you see the pattern?

Comment: Oops, I actually meant $\log(1-x)$

Comment: Oh okay, I assumed linearilty.

Comment: @sidht For the function $\log{1 - x}$, the proof is almost identical; the derivatives just pick up a minus sign and every instance of $x$ is replaced by $1 - x$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach

$$ \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k \implies \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1-t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} t^k dt =\dots\,. $$

Note that, we can integrate the series term by term within its radius of convergence.

Comment: Right, that's what i was going for.